# Dataconversion warning with Standard Scaler. Int converted to float64, but there are no integers

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Here are the `dtypes` of my dataframe, all floats:

```
data.dtypes

TOTPOP16    float64
AGEDEP16    float64
LONEPA16    float64
EDLOW_16    float64
EDHIGH16    float64
HLPROF16    float64
LSKILL16    float64
UNEMPM16    float64
UNEMPF16    float64
PEROOM16    float64
LARENT16    float64
PRRENT16    float64
OHOUSE16    float64
SCORE       float64
```

However when I use Sklearn's standardScaler it warns me that integers are being converted to float64. I don't have any integers as you can see.

What is happening and how can I disable this warning?

```
scaler.fit_transform(x_train)


C:\Users\s\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py:645: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64, float64 were all converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
  return self.partial_fit(X, y)
C:\Users\s\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:464: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64, float64 were all converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
  return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
```

Comment: IIUC, `standardScaler` scales the features so as your data has mean 0 and std 1, i.e. `(x-mean)/std`. That doesn't (and shouldn't) look like integers.

Comment: Whats your sklearn version?

Comment: Scikit learn version 0.20.3